# How to open .dmp oracle backup file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dmp

I have a **backup.dmp** file, which is backup file of my database built in oracle. please suggest me how can I see tables, schema etc stored in that backup.dmp ? should I install some software to open this backup.dmp file.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

.dmp files have been generated by oracle tools (data pump or maybe export). To exploit this  files, you need to install Oracle (try for exemple oracle 10g express) and then use the import(imp) or data pump (impdb)

Answer (score 1):

You can view the dump file contents using Toad (must be fully licensed with the DBA extension), imp or impdp.

```
impdp scott/tiger@orcl directorory=dpump sqlfile-abc.sql dumpfile=xyz.dmp and logfile=xyz_log.log full=y
```

Or

```
imp scott/tiger@orcl file=abc.dmp show=y log=abc_log.log full=y
```

These commands will create viewable DDL of the actual DB creation.